# KeyError while fetching MNIST data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, mnist

I'm trying to play around MNSIT dataset and here is the error I got in the very beginning.
[Error while fetching MNIST image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Xyt8.jpg)

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
mnist = fetch_openml('mnist_784')
x, y = mnist['data'], mnist['target']
digit = x[36001]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x` is 2-dimensional; try this:

```
digit = x[36001, :]
```

Since, you're facing an error, which must be due to x being not treated as a `numpy array`, try the following two methods:

```
digit = x.iloc[36001, :]
```

Or

```
digit = x.to_numpy()[36001,:]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, I tried this but unfortunately, it threw up another error. TypeError: '(3601, slice(None, None, None))' is an invalid key

Comment: Can you please check what is the shape of variable x ? Use: `x.shape` to check

Comment: I'm not sure why you're getting the error, I tried the code and it works for me. https://imgur.com/117fKyU

Comment: Yeah, I'm still facing the same error. You can check here. https://imgur.com/FRsa9f8 Also, can you please try running it in Jupyter notebook as well?

Comment: It is working for me in Jupyter notebook as well: https://imgur.com/6fwVONJ,  however I think I have figured out your problem, it might be due to `x` not being treated as a numpy array. Please check the edit.

Comment: I tried changing the variable name 'x' as well. Is it right that the data type which I'm getting here is DataFrame? https://imgur.com/UIrtRor Everything going haywire in this problem.

Comment: Yes, the datatype for `x` is a `DataFrame` and that is creating all the problem. You can convert `x` to a `numpy array` using x.to_numpy() and then everything would be fine.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! btw what might be the reason for it showing as a data frame in my system but an array in others.

Comment: This intrigued me as well so I was searching around but couldn't find the reason, sorry

Comment: I came across this bug after updating several packages (including scikit-learn). Maybe they recently changed `fetch_openml` to return pandas DataFrames instead of numpy arrays?

Answer (score 3):

Expanding my comment, I think the MNIST dataset of openml was recently (?) switched to return a pandas DataFrame instead of a numpy array. Another possible fix is in the function call:

```
mnist = fetch_openml('mnist_784', as_frame=False)
```

Comment: Oh great, this worked very well too. Thanks for this update :-D